# xquery - query for recover parents node

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have this file xml:

```
<EV id="000" age="10">
   <specie cod="e00"/> 
   <acc child="002"/>
</EV>
<EV id="001" age="12">
   <specie cod="e01"/> 
   <acc child="002"/>
</EV>
<EV id="002" age="2">
   <specie cod="e00"/> 
   <acc/>
</EV>
<EV id="003" age="30">
   <specie cod="e00"/> 
   <acc child="005"/>
</EV>
<EV id="004" age="20">
   <specie cod="e00"/> 
   <acc child="005"/>
</EV>
<EV id="005" age="5">
   <specie cod="e00"/> 
   <acc/>
</EV>
```

Now I must print how results the attributes @id of tags  (the children of my project) that appears in other two tags  (the parents) in the tags  but the two tags  (the parents) must to have the attributes @cod in tag  different. Another condiction is that the different age from the two parents is minor < of 5 years (10 and 12 is good, 20 and 30 no).

Example for the xml above: the xquery must print only id="002".

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a version using predicates a lot:

```
for $e in /EV
return $e[count(distinct-values(../EV[acc/@child = $e/@id]/specie/@cod)) = 2][abs(../EV[acc/@child = $e/@id][1]/@age - ../EV[acc/@child = $e/@id][2]/@age) < 5]
```

However, I would probably prefer a more readable version:

```
for $parent in /EV
let $childs := $parent/../EV[acc/@child = $parent/@id]
where
  count(distinct-values($childs/specie/@cod)) = 2
  and
  abs($childs[1]/@age - $childs[2]/@age) < 5
return $parent
```

Comment: Yes, the tags "children" have always two parents. What's ther after /@id/data( ? Thanks for your answer, tomorrow I try.

Comment: @LocalHero sorry, I didn't copy the closing paranthesis.

Comment: your solution is good @dirkk, thanks :) Is it possible add this ultimate condiction? "Another condiction is that the different age from the two parents is minor < of 5 years (10 and 12 is good, 20 and 30 no)." I have edited the original message and xml file with the attribute age. Thanks for the ultimate help.